How to install Fujitsu KB SCR ESIG keyboard drivers on Ubuntu?
I run Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS and have Fujitsu KB SCR ESIG keyboard. The keys are recognized, I can write with it, but the card reader doesn't seem to read the keycard when it's inserted so I was looking for ways to fix that.
There seem to be no Linux drivers for this keyboard though, is there any way to install the Windows drivers on Ubuntu and have them be used?
https://support.ts.fujitsu.com/Search/SWP1088312.asp
Or any other ideas for a solution?
